# Finding remainder of negative number

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

Recently my colleague ask one mathematical question which is,

> What is the quotient and remainder of $(-29)/7$?

and my answer was that quotient is $4$ and remainder is $-1$ and he told me I'm completely wrong. He said that the reminder will be $6$, and I'm really get stuck here how will the remainder be $6$.

> EDIT:

**Sorry for my great mistake, the question will be $(-29)/7$ and his result was quotient is $-5$ and remainder is $6$**

Comment: To clarify:  the question concerns $\frac{-29}{7}$, yes?  Even so, I can't see where -10 might come into it.

Comment: I'm pretending the question was about $-29/7$ and that somewhere in the transcription the order has been lost.

Comment: And that "quotient is 4" should read "quotient is -4".

Comment: Saying "the quotient is -4 with a remainder of -1" is, at least, consistent with my reading of the problem.  Some writers prefer to insist that remainders be non-negative.  In that case, one could say that "the quotient is -5 with a remainder of 6".  Nothing I can think of gives me a -10 which makes me think I am not seeing the original problem properly.

Comment: @mixedmath, Yes the question is (-29)/7. I'm sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should ask him exactly what he means when he says remainder. It is common for us to mean the following:

For any two integers $a,b$, with $a \neq 0$, there exist unique integers $q,r$ such that
$$ b = aq + r$$
where $0 \leq r < |a|$. Then we call $q$ the "quotient" and $r$ the "remainder." This fact is sometimes called the [division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm), but it implicitly contains our definitions of quotient and remainder. In particular, we are demanding that the remainder be positive.

With $-29$ and $7$, we have that
$$ -29 = 7\cdot(-5) + 6,$$
so that according to my definition of remainder we would get $6$.

As an aside, there is no reasonable way to get $-10$ as a remainder, regardless of definition.

Comment: I'm sorry my asked question was wrong. Thanks for explanation, now I'm understand this.

Comment: There are cases (error free arithmetic for example) where it convenient to have $|a|/2 \lt r \le |a|/2$, in which case $r = -1$ is the appropriate answer.