# What is the remainder in $-25÷2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

While solving my homework in Math, I just thought of this and I don't know if it's correct. I've never done the simple division in negative number, so it's a little confusing if the remainder in $-25÷2$ must be negative. When we multiply the quotient by $2$ and add back $-1$ , I got $-25$. so I can say that the remainder in $25÷(-2)$ must be $1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, although I would also confirm with your teacher. See, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352776/finding-remainder-of-negative-number) as well.

Comment: "When we multiply the quotient by 2"  (what is the quotient?  Is it $-12$?  Is it $-13$?  Something else "and add back −1 , I got −25. so I can say that the remainder in 25÷(−2) must be 1"  Well if the remainder is what you "add back" then that means the remainder must be $-1$ as that is what you added back.   .... But *is* that the convention in your class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematicians have the convention that for any $n$ (in this case $n=-25$) and a divisor $q$ (in this case $q= 2$) then there is a unique pair of integers $d$ (which may be positive, negative, or $0$) and $r$ (which *must* be so that $0\le r < q$) so that $n = dq + r$.

In this case those unique integers so that $-25 = d\times 2 + r$ where $0 \le r < 2$ are $-25 = (-13)\times 2 + 1$ so $d = -13$ and $r = 1$.

So the remainder is $r=1$.

(Note:  If $n$ is negative then $|md| > n$ which might be counterintuitive as we are multiplying $2$ by negative numbers to do $-2, -4, -6,....., -20,-22,-24,-26$ and we go *past* $-25$.  Mathematicians figure this is okay as we want remainders to be non-negative always.  We find that to be more consistent.)

Computer scientists, so for as I can tell, have a different convention that $d$ can be positive or negative.  And $|r|< q$ but $r$ is the same sign as $d$

So $-25  = (-12)\times 2 - 1$ so $r = -1$ and to a computer scientist $d = -12$ and  the remainder is $r=-1$.

(Note: this way we are multiplying be $-2$ and getting $-2,-4, -6,......, -20, -22, -24$ and we *don't* go past $-25$. This is okay to them as a remainder can be negative and can be thought of how far past the $-24$ term we need to go.)

Ask you teach which convention you are expected to use.  But the conventional mathematician one is remainders are $0$ or positive.  Never negative.

Answer (score 0):

The [Division Algorithm Theorem](http://www.math.niu.edu/%7Erichard/Math303/ch1pt4.pdf) (in $\mathbb{Z}$) establishes that: if $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $b > 0$, then there exists unique $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
a=bq+r, \quad 0 \leq r < |b|. \tag{1}
$$

By taking in particular $a=-25$ and $b=2$, we have that $(1)$ holds, for $q=-13$ and $r=1>0$. Therefore, the remainder of the division $-\tfrac{25}{2}$ is $r=1$.

Comment: Check $q=-13,r=1$. (Note : downvote not mine)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Sorry my mistake. I fixed.

Comment: Thank you, and +1!

Answer (score 0):

We usually require the remainder when we divide by $n$ to be between $0$ and $n-1$, so here the remainder MUST be $0$ or $1$. This is so we can write $-25$ in a unique way $$-25 = -13(2)+1.$$

The $-13$ that pops up is actually related to the greatest integer function: it is the greatest integer less than $-25/2$. It is true that for *positive* numbers, this equals the "whole" part when we write it in decimal form.

Comment: This is one convention but not the only one. E.g. most computer programming languages would return $-12$ and $-1$ for the quotient and remainder in this case. Without further context from the OP it's not clear which convention is appropriate.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I had no idea. [For reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)